# hook_schema() not getting uninstalled when module is disabled

Tags: drupal

I have installed a schema for a custom module which creates the table when I enable the module. But when I disable the module, the table still remains. I am using the following code for uninstall:

```php
function sample2_install() {
  if(!db_table_exists('contact')){
    drupal_install_schema('sample2');
  }
}

function sample2_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema('sample2');
}
```

Why is the table not getting uninstalled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference here is between disabling and uninstalling. Disabling keeps the module settings ready to go whenever it gets reinabled. Uninstalling purges everything until it is re-enabled.

[`hook_uninstall()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7) only gets called when you fully uninstall the module.
[`hook_disable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) gets called when you only disable it.

You could call [`drupal_uninstall_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_uninstall_schema/7) if inside of [`hook_disable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7), but I don't recommend that. It would mean that all your data gets deleted when you disable the module — generally uninstalling is when you would want to completely delete everything.

Comment: So if i need to uninstall the table whenever i disable the module, how would i go about doing that? What I am guessing is that the hook_uninstall is never getting called since I am just disabling the module.

Comment: @user550265, you should not remove tables when a module is disabled. That is the whole point of disabling: that data is not nuked. The sole (and only) difference between uninstalling and disabling, is that the first (irrevokably) removes data and the last doesn't.

Comment: If you *really* want all the data to be deleted when the module is disabled, just add drupal_uninstall_schema to your call hook_disable. I reccomend against this approach, since it's not normal behavior for a Drupal module. You can uninstall modules as www.yoursite.com/admin/build/modules/uninstall

Comment: Or, you could just call module_invoke('yourmodule', 'uninstall') inside of hook_disable. This will make disabling equivalent to uninstalling for that particular module. But, you're not going to do that because we've convinced you that nuking all a module's data when it is disabled is a bad idea, right?

Comment: *"You could call drupal_uninstall_schema() if inside of hook_uninstall, but I don't recommend that."* @anschauung
This makes no sense, hook_uninstall is exactly what this hook is for. Am i missing something?

Comment: @zfreak: You're exactly right -- that was a typo. I've corrected the sentence to read "You could call drupal_uninstall_schema() if inside of hook_disable" which is what I meant.

Comment: Just a note for Drupal 7 developers: _"A module no longer should explicitly install or uninstall its database schema in hook_install() or hook_uninstall()."_, see: https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#install-schema